# Div.Show does not work when running, but does work when stepping through code

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, jquery

I have a div that should appear when saving. The markup for this is similar to this:

```
<div class="Working" style="display: none;">Message</div>
```

Later in my code I have some save logic, which does this:

```
function SaveData() {
    var cancelSave = false;

    $('.Working').text('Saving data ...').show();
    var saveData = { 'Data': myData }; // Actually a lot of logic in here

    if (cancelSave) {
        $('.Working').hide();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            // bunch of stuff here
            async: false, // tried this both ways
            error: function (rsp) {
                $('.Working').hide();
            },
            success: function (rsp) {
                $('.Working').text('Saved');
                $('.Working').fadeOut(5000, DoNothing());
            }
        });
    }
}

function DoNothing() {
    // Does nothing
}
```

If I step through the code, the div shows up perfectly when I step through the initial .show() line. However, when I run this at "full speed" ... I never see the "Saving data ..." message. The actual save does take about 5-7 seconds, so there is plenty of time to see the message.

Comment: I'll guess that somewhere in "a lot of logic" you're setting `cancelSave` to true, or the ajax call fails. As a sidenote, the callback for the `fadeout` doesn't work as it's not referenced but called, and neither does the `fadeout` as it has the wrong case

Comment: Trying using a .hidden { display: none } instead of inline styles.

Comment: I do love the DoNothing function :).

Comment: And.... never ever ever ever use async false, it defeats the entire purpose of ajax

Comment: try removing all the `$('.Working').hide();` lines, then adding them back in one at a time and seeing when you stop seeing the div.

Comment: I tried to abbreviate a huge amount of code here in a readable block. Sorry about the typo - I had the fadeOut correct in the actual page.

Comment: When you step through with the debugger, my guess is there is enough of a delay for the call to return. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Also, I use the inline style="display: none;" a bit because I've found that sometimes if I use javascript to initially hide elements they will flicker briefly on load.

Comment: @trgraglia this was my thought as well .. but I am not sure how to give the element the delay it needs to update. The entire process of saving takes over 5 seconds, so if I need to add a small time-slice for that to display, I'm fine (assuming we're talking 100ms or so).

Comment: How is `cancelSave` supposed to work? Is the user supposed to be able to cancel the save before the function completes? Because that wont happen as the function with reach `$.ajax` synchronously. If you are going to allow a user to cancel a save, it probably needs to be another ajax call to tell the server to cancel the first. Also this: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging you should be able to set a breakpoint and learn all the things.

Comment: @Fresheyeball In the logic that builds the saveData object, cancelSave can be set to true if a problem is found in one of the input elements that wasn't handled previously.

Comment: Setup a jsFiddle. Without the cancelSave being global, how is it being updated? You need to show more code before we can help more.

Comment: @ESDictor set a breakpoint, what is the value of cancelSave at the time of the if statement?

Comment: @trgraglia please repost your answer. I'm not sure what worked of the many things I've tried, but it now appears to be working. The biggest change I made WAS the async from false to true, so I'm going to mark that as correct.

Comment: @ESDictor It has been undeleted. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI is locked up because the ajax `async` property is set to `false`. Set it to `true` and try it. The `SaveData` method will finish, update the UI to show the "saving data..." text and then update again when the ajax call returns.

Comment: I have tried with async: true and async: false with no change to the outcome. I never see the "Working" div when running .. only when stepping through in Chrome.

Comment: Does chrome show any errors when the debugging console is open but no breakpoints are set?

Comment: @ESDictor How did you solve this problem? I have the same issue with Chrome and it's working fine on Firefox...